mergeing pdfs with same name in 2 different folders error
i tried this code but i'm getting this error
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './first_folder/same_name.pdf'


from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger #pip install PyPDF2


  def merge_pdf(file_name, first_folder, second_folder, output_folder):
      merger = PdfMerger()

      merger.append(f"{first_folder}/{file_name}")
      merger.append(f"{second_folder}/{file_name}")

      merger.write(f"{output_folder}/merged_file.pdf")

    
  merge_pdf('same_name.pdf','./first_folder','./second_folder', './output_folder')

the files with the same name to be merged in a different folder
